# Return the smallest circle in the from the list of circles

Tags: python, recursion

I am working with recursions in python. I have two functions r(coord) that returns the radius of a circle with the center at the given coordinates and inside(coord) that returns the set of centers of all circles directly inside the circle with the given center.

I want to calculate the surface of all circles and I want to return the center of the smallest circle. I have already written the function for surface:

```
def surface(coord):
        return sum([surface(x) for x in inside(coord)], r(coord) * r(coord) * pi)
```

Now I want to return the center of the smallest circle with recursion in one return. This is what I have written:

```
def smallest(coord):
    return min(inside(coord))
```

But this line of code outputs the different result then what I'm expecting.

```
Expected :(20, 10.625) <-- The one I get
Actual   :(16.25, 12.5) <-- The result I want the smallest circle
```

I'm stuck at this function and I'm not quite sure how to approach the problem or what the solution is.

This is my entire code

```
def r(coord):
    return {(0, 10): 7.5,
            (0, 6): 2.5,
            (3.75, 12.5): 2.5,
            (3.75, 11.25): 1.25,
            (-3.75, 12.5): 2.5,
            (-5, 12.5): 1.25,

            (20, 10): 7.5, (20, 6): 2.5,
            (23.75, 12.5): 2.5, (23.75, 11.25): 1.25,
            (16.25, 12.5): 2.5, (15, 12.5): 1.25,
            (20, 10.625): 0.625,

            (-2.5, -8.75): 8.75,
            (-8.125, -4.375): 0.625,
            (-1.875, -9.375): 6.875,
            (-1.25, -10): 5,
            (-1.25, -9.25): 3.75,
            (-0.625, -10.625): 1.875,

            (21.25, -16.25): 11.25,
            (21.25, -7.5): 2.5,
            (22.5, -7.5): 1.25,
            (25.625, -13.125): 3.125,
            (26.875, -11.875): 0.625,
            (26.25, -21.25): 3.75,
            (16.25, -21.25): 3.75,
            (16.25, -22.25): 2.5,
            (16.125, -22.875): 0.875,
            (16.25, -12.5): 3.75
            }[coord]



def inside(coord):
    inside1 = {(0, 10): [(0, 6), (3.75, 12.5), (-3.75, 12.5)],
             (0, 6): [],
             (3.75, 12.5): [(3.75, 11.25)],
             (3.75, 11.25): [],
             (-3.75, 12.5): [(-5, 12.5)],
             (-5, 12.5): [],

             (20, 10): [(20, 6), (23.75, 12.5), (16.25, 12.5), (20, 10.625)],
             (20, 6): [],
             (23.75, 12.5): [(23.75, 11.25)],
             (23.75, 11.25): [],
             (16.25, 12.5): [(15, 12.5)],
             (15, 12.5): [],
             (20, 10.625): [],

             (-2.5, -8.75): [(-8.125, -4.375), (-1.875, -9.375)],
             (-8.125, -4.375): [],
             (-1.875, -9.375): [(-1.25, -10)],
             (-1.25, -10): [(-1.25, -9.25)],
             (-1.25, -9.25): [(-0.625, -10.625)],
             (-0.625, -10.625): [],

             (21.25, -16.25): [(21.25, -7.5), (25.625, -13.125),
                               (26.25, -21.25), (16.25, -21.25),
                               (16.25, -12.5)],
             (21.25, -7.5): [(22.5, -7.5)],
             (22.5, -7.5): [],
             (25.625, -13.125): [(26.875, -11.875)],
             (26.875, -11.875): [],
             (26.25, -21.25): [],
             (16.25, -21.25): [(16.25, -22.25)],
             (16.25, -22.25): [(16.125, -22.875)],
             (16.125, -22.875): [],
             (16.25, -12.5): []}[coord]
    random.shuffle(inside1)
    return inside1

def surface(coord):
    return sum([surface(x) for x in inside(coord)], r(coord) * r(coord) * pi)


def smallest(coord):
    return min(inside(coord)) <-- wrong output
```

Comment: `inside` returns a list of coordinates (pairs of floats), so you are taking the minimum of some pairs. Don't you want to take the minimum of the radii?

Comment: I don't see any recursion here.

Comment: @JohnGordon no I want to my function to be recursive

Comment: @md2perpe hmm maybe this is better approach.

Comment: there is no recursion in your code

Comment: @Eternal oh I see. Do you know how should I have written the function smallest then? I'm a bit confused atm.

Comment: @RoninHunter You can give a `key` argument to function `min`. Try `return min(inside(coord), key=r)`

Comment: Note: I suggest making `r` a dictionary instead of a function. Just write `r = { (0, 10): 7.5, ... }`. Then you can call `r[coord]` directly instead of `r(coord)` in the rest of your code.

Comment: @Stef this is how I have written my return: `return min([smallest(x) for x in inside(coord)], key=r)`  which is almost correct it is only missing one argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. It outputed the right coordinates. It loops through all the circles and finds the smallest and then stores them coord. This is the code:

```
return min([coord]+[smallest(x) for x in inside(coord)], key=r)
```